# Code for n-sided prism in OpenGL

Tags: c++, math, opengl

is there any code to calculate and draw an n-sided prism in OpenGL? It should work like

```
void DrawPrism(long sides) {

 glNormal3f( ...);
 glTexCoord2f(..);
 glVertex3f(...);
 [...]

}


DrawPrism(5)
```

[image]

Basically all I need is the **x - y - position of the edges of the base**. The rest of the calculation is done by GL.

Comment: do you mean doing it automatically? Or you ask for the whole code to make it?. If it´s the second one, that´s a bad question to ask here. Here is just for questions, not for making people do things for you for free :-)

Comment: Do you mean n-gon or n-hedron? (2D or 3D)?

Comment: Hi, it is meant to work automatically. Maybe someone can contribute the code for a 5 or 6-sided one that he already wrote, that we could transform together. It is meant in 3D.

Comment: @darkgaze I really hope someone **alread did** that because it is not a standard function of GL...

Comment: Oh. :-(    Then, i don´t know. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New Answer:

To calculate the coordinates of the vertices of a pentagon check out the video I made for you here:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqu6LknbQsg

To calculate the height of the pentagon the equation is: [image]
^Retrieved from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=height%20of%20a%20penatgon&a=*C.penatgon-_*Geometry-)

---

FILL by Kenobi:
As explained in the video above, A,B,C,D,E are the edges of the pentagon. F,G,H,I,J are the second pentagon to form a prism together. Sin and cos is measured in degrees. Then we have following vertices:

```
  Ax = 0                 ; Ay = h/2,               ; Az = -1;
  Bx = s/2 + s * sin(18) ; By = -h/2 + s*cos(18)   ; Bz = -1;
  Cx = s/2               ; Cy = -h/2               ; Cz = -1;
  Dx = -s/2              ; Dy = -h/2               ; Dz = -1;
  Ex = -s/2 - s * sin(18); Ey = -h/2 + s*cos(18)   ; Ez = -1;

  Fx = 0                 ; Fy = h/2,               ; Fz = 1;
  Gx = s/2 + s * sin(18) ; Gy = -h/2 + s*cos(18)   ; Gz = 1;
  Hx = s/2               ; Hy = -h/2               ; Hz = 1;
  Ix = -s/2              ; Iy = -h/2               ; Iz = 1;
  Jx = -s/2 - s * sin(18); Jy = -h/2 + s*cos(18)   ; Jz = 1;
```

and then you simply do

```
glVertex3f(Ax,Ay,Az); 
glVertex3f(Bx,By,Bz);
[...]
```

---

---

Edit: previous answer below (*For all polygons, not just pentagons):

---

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWbTKm3a5Fw) is the video I made **FOR YOU** on how to generate any 2D n-gon... to generate any 3D shape (n-hedron) you can either compose it of these different n-gons using the mathematical "net" (skeleton structure) of the 3D object and calculate the angles (all of these formulas can be found by searching for the n-hedron interior angle formula or the n-hedron _____) Or you could draw them the same way I drew these n-gons (in the video) just using different colored lines to simulate shading (but you will have to turn them in 3D space, which I know you can do in c++ so you're fine.

Anyways, **here is my video**: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWbTKm3a5Fw

And this is what a Geometrical-net is (refereed to earlier) incase you were wondering:
[image]

This article show math used in calculating things like n-hedron interior angles of faces and what-not, could be VERY helpful: http://www.kjmaclean.com/Geometry/IcosaDodeca.html

Comment: Hello @albert-renshaw , thank you SOOOO much for your work! I went through the whole video. I made an explanatory picture for you (and all the others) to understand the challenge. I only need the positions of the edges as a point (x|y) - think of it maybe as a recoursive function that jumps from one edge to the next, giving us the coordinates, until it reaches where it started. Filling and texturing is done automagically by OpenGL - we don't worry for that part ;-)

Comment: Oh, so you just need the x,y coordinates of the vertices of any given n-gon, you are making a prism of that n-gon so you aren't looking for an n-hedron (like I mentioned above with the nets) you are looking for an n-prism... So in the video the method I discussed for solving an n-gon will still work (even for just getting the x,y coordinates of the vertices, it's just calculations.) and then you can shift if up in 3d space and fill in the edges. Cool! Good luck, man!

Comment: So the X,Y coordinates of the vertices of any n-gon (polygon) are just the 3 most evenly placed apart locations on a circle (since all n-gons can be circumscribed.) See here: http://dr282zn36sxxg.cloudfront.net/datastreams/f-d%3A9f99b71ca1ff3f1cb9fcc3da7ae8c1e31a81364703b755c0676fc2b7%2BIMAGE%2BIMAGE.1

Comment: hey @albert-renshaw , your last post sounds very promising, but how to implement that!? However, we are short before a final implementation for a 5-sided prism, I finished all the code fore a random one, for a regular one I would only need two formulas: imagine a standing 5-sided polygon. If I know the length of the base (b), which is the width (w) and the height(h) of the 5-gon?

Comment: If you know the height and width than you can calculate the "second width" meaning not the base's width but the width of the two vertices which you don't know the location of using the methods I mentioned in the video... use sine or the interior angle minus 90 times the width of the base and multiply that answer by 2, now add that answer to the base and it's the length of the middle cross-section segment. You can center that it find the x,y vertices from that, I will make a new video explaining just that process if you need it— sometimes text makes it hard to explain :o) Good luck! God bless!

Comment: @Kenobi Take this pentagon for example: http://www.mathscareers.org.uk/_db/_images/homeandaway1.jpg
If you need to know the x-location of E and you know the x-location of D than you would just use M-(D-C)*(sin(18º))=N where "M" is the x-location of "D" and "N" is the x-location of "E" that you are trying to solve for. (D-C) is the width of the base.

Comment: @Kenobi for the y-coordinate you would simply use "cosine" instead of "sine" in that formula I mentioned above. (this time "M" would be the y-location" of "D" and "N" is the "y-location" of "E" that you are trying to solve for.

Comment: @Kenobi Point "A" would obviously just be the y-location of "D" or "C" plus the Height of the pentagon and point "A"'s x-location would just be the x-location of "D" plus the x-location of "C" divide by 2 (basically just the middle of the pentagon. Good luck!

Comment: Hey @albert-renshaw, thanks again for your help, but its way too much text for tonight :-) I'll go over it tomorrow, my preferred solution would be a bunch of plain formula like :  Ex = base * sin * bla  , Ey = base * sin * bla;  Bx = -Ex; By= Ey (that last two are actually true :-)) ,   and so on, assuming, F is at (0,0), and base is the length of every side. If you want to make a video, then it would be awesome if it was like this :-D

Comment: Hey @Albert-Renshaw, that seems to do the trick! We only need to add the equation for "h" which is, according to the internet,   SideLength * (cos(18) + sin(36))  (didn't verify that but sounds correct), and then finished finding the vertex positions! (basically adding the height to it as a third dimension is trivial). If you put that all in an answer below, I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Kenobi Thanks! I edited it all into my original answer, you can accept it :o) God bless!

Comment: @Kenobi Also, I don't know if that's the formula for height... although it may work, there's certainly a way to do it by adding up the height of 2 triangles using cos and sin, but the formula I provided will work, I haven't confirmed yours.. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Kenobi Is there anything else I need to do to get it accepted?

Comment: Hi Albert, I actually edited in another paragraph in your answer, stackoverflow said it needed a "peer review" to publish that.

Comment: @Kenobi It should be good now, your edit was rejected by the peers because it changed to much of my answer but I over-rode that.

Comment: Hi @Albert-Renshaw, finally we are done! But it was a pleasure working with you :-)

Comment: @Kenobi Like Wise! God bless:)

Answer (score 1):

No. Even in Glut there is not a function to create it. Sadly you will have to create it by hand.
Basic quadrics are not on basic OpenGL. Using GLUT you have some functions:

http://www.cs.csustan.edu/~rsc/SDSU/Modeling.GLU.GLUT.pdf

But nothing more.